# vue component library not working together with vuetify in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, babeljs, vuetify.js

I created a single button vue library and built it via vue-cli-service build --target lib.
And this option works fine in nuxtjs, but when I include vuetify in my package and try to use it in nuxtjs, the app throws an error
In nuxtjs I include vuetify via @nuxtjs/vuetify
Please help because I don't understand what is the problem.

My package.json  in library

```
{
  "name": "uikit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name uikit src/index.js",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "module": "./dist/uikit.common.js",
  "main": "./dist/uikit.umd.js",
  "files": [
    "./dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

With <button> in the library it works fine and even @click works
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A61xW.png)

What do I see when I use v-btn in my library
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvRx.png)

As you can see, when using v-btn in my application, apart from an error in the console, vuetify does not work completely except for styles

In nuxt.config.js
set build
`transpile: \['@nuxtjs/vuetify'\] or transpile: \['vuetify'\]`
also `plugins: \[new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()\]` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated `nuxt.config.js` the way it says in the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#nuxt-install) and the [nuxtjs/vuetify plugin page](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module)?

```js
// nuxt.config.js
{
  buildModules: [
    // Simple usage
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',

    // With options
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify', { /* module options */ }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure. but the error remains.
I also collected a test library, but with rollup. then I connected vuetify and everything worked.
only with treeshaking enabled, you have to import vuetify components from 'vuetify/lib' in the library

Comment: if you disable treeshaking then there is no need to import in the library, for example, when using the v-btn button.